# Approach to analysing data on 2 medical devices on the same patient

Tags: hypothesis-testing, t-test, mean, differences

I am currently evaluating a new device compared to a gold standard device. Each person is measured at the same time with both devices and I want to know how to investigate the results.

My question is how to approach the data analysis. Calculate the difference between the 2 measures and then? I need to be able to show statistical significance. I had assumed a 2 tailed ttest would be used, but got confused. Just some general advice would be appropriated. I'm assuming there's no difference between the devices.

Thankyou in advance.